# Custom V3 router (Is it a Universal router)

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uniswapv3, swaps, router

I came accross a concept i have no idea about. The concept of custom router. As per my research may be Uniswap V3 is offering Universal router. Is it possible to deploy instance of universal router as our own custom router?? one example of custom router is https://etherscan.io/address/0xdb5889e35e379ef0498aae126fc2cce1fbd23216.
Need help to understand this idea.

Second part of question is that if I have to decode its transaction how do i do it. here is one of the function call details.

Function: 0x70fef1da ***

MethodID: 0x70fef1da
[0]:  000000000000000000000000456ed7ad0b99f4495e95619b7e2aa8598a2d6abb
[1]:  000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2
[2]:  0000000000000000000000007a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d
[3]:  0000000000000000000000000b72cbefb8790fe4eef0dcbbd1ea3e51472b417c
[4]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[5]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[6]:  0000000000000000000000005200a0e9b161bc59feecb165fe2592bef3e1847a
[7]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
[8]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006
[9]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032
[10]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
[11]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033
[12]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
[13]: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006501a25f
[14]: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Sure you can fork and deploy it. You can also modify it to do anything you want. Why though?

Comment: I got the point, any guidance for function call and is it possible to implement copy trading on these custom routers?

Comment: @MalikMehmood Uniswap has an SDK with javascript wrappers to perform any swap. You could try adapting them to your contracts.

Answer (score 0):

I am newby in all of this but maybe this can help you. I am identifying some params using etherscan and the trx data, and making a mapping of the methods used. For example in this one you shared the methodId as you said is 0x70fef1da and the srcToken (1st byte) and dstToken (2nd byte) are 456ed7ad0b99f4495e95619b7e2aa8598a2d6abb (Reprint (REPRINT)) and c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2 (WETH).

In my case, the 4th byte is the be the amount of srcToken. But I am still trying to figure out all that data.

Hope it helps